# How to bring 2 image for connect together (not merge)

Tags: java, image, connect

http://image.ohozaa.com/view/6fcjh

[image]

How to do this with Java Source code

I can merge that
but i can not to connect that like this pictue

Answer (score 1):

Put each image in an `ImageIcon`, then each `Icon` in a `JLabel`, and then add both `JLabels` to a `JPanel` that uses `GridLayout(2, 1)` (2 rows, 1 column).

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to combine multiple Icons into a single Icon. See [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/).

Comment: This is a nice slick solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
        File path = new File("images");

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path, "1 (1).jpg"));
        BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File(path, "1 (2).jpg"));

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight()+ overlay.getHeight();
        BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(overlay, 0, image.getHeight(), null);

        ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File(path, "combined 2.png"));
```

Comment: Code answers are best with commentary. Please add some context to your answer.