# how to connect 2 images together to display on a website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've done a lot of research and found nothing that will let me connect 2 images together.
is there some kind of plugin that I could use?
I want my results to look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552806/how-to-bring-2-image-for-connect-together-not-merge), but i want to do it when a webpage is loaded with a specific image that needs this kind of adjustment, obviously using php and mysql to call those images.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What constitutes 'a lot of research'? You wouldn't have to look far to find how to create and add to images in PHP, which is essentially what you want to do.

Comment: i can't find any tutorials or anything saying that this is possible, maybe I've been looking in the wrong places

Comment: Don't you think you could adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394061/how-to-merge-transparent-png-with-image-using-php) to suit your needs? Usually people at least attempt what they are trying and then come here with a specific problem.

Comment: I couldn't attempt it, I had no idea where to start with something like this, but I just managed the fine the answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858489/merge-two-images-in-php?rq=1). thank you for your help sorry for the unnecessary question

Answer (score 0):

It's not a programming issue, it's simply a HTML/CSS problem. Instead of a 2-line code, there is the howto:

- You should set proper position for the two (half) images. Fortunatelly, by default, two adjacent <div> tags are aligned to the same vertical position, there is no reason for different default positioning strategy.
- There are some style properties which can produce gap between two DIVs or IMGs: *border, padding, margin* (and any character in <pre> blocks). Eliminate them.
- If you set *display* property of the <img> to *block*, you need no wrapping <div> elements (maybe this is the default for <img> tags, but it's not a mistake if you define it).
- If you're using tables, there are some other table-spefific properties which can produce gaps. But if you don't really need, don't use tables for layouts.